# Reloading the backbone view and i18n translation file in Backbone Application?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, rails-i18n

I am using i18n.js in BackboneJS application for Text localization. but stuck at a point where i need reload the text translation on language change in the application. i am calling setting view render() function on language change but doesn't work for me, but on reloading index.html it works. So How can i reload the translation file and view to reflect the changes. below is what i tried--

application-bootstrap.js

```
var locale = {};

    locale.language = "en-us";//default

    locale.setLanguage = function (language) {
        localStorage.setItem('localLanguage', '' + language);
    };

    locale.getLanguage = function () {
        return localStorage.getItem('localLanguage');
    };
    require.config({
        config: {
            i18n: {
                locale: locale.getLanguage()
            }
        }
    });
```

settingView.js

```
define(['compiled/settingTmpl','i18n!nls/setting'
], function (SettingTmpl,setting) {
    'use strict';

    var SettingView = Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            "change #languageSelect": "changeLocale"
        },
        initialize: function () {
            WellNation.helper.log("Setting view initialize");
            this.render();
        },
        changeLocale: function (e) {
            var locale = e.currentTarget.value;
            WellNation.locale.setLanguage(locale);
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(SettingTmpl({speak:setting}));
            return this;
        }
    });

    return SettingView;
});
```

settingTmpl.handlebars

```
<div class="row">
        <label>{{speak.language}}</label>
        <select id="languageSelect">
            <option value="en-us">English (United States)</option>
            <option value="fr-fr">Francais (France)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

nls/fr-fr/setting.js

```
  define({
      "language" : "langue"
    });
```

nls/setting.js

```
  define({
      "root" : {
      "language" : "Language"
      },
      "fr-fr" : true // The system will accept French
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256479/setting-requirejs-i18n-locale-dynamically) SO question and [this github issue](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/213) it's not possible to change locale at runtime with i18n.js.

**From official docs it's not clear could we use it at runtime or not:** "*RequireJS will use the browser's navigator.language or navigator.userLanguage property to determine what locale values to use for my/nls/colors, so your app does not have to change. If you prefer to set the locale, you can use the module config to pass the locale to the plugin*"

So after some researches and walk throw the i18n.js source code I found that the best solution for you will be to keep the same structure and use `location.reload()`.

Comment: Thankyou Vahan for you time, is there any other alternative solution which i can implement.

Comment: This is the case when solutions limited by technology. You can implement your own mechanism of internationalization. For example you could load all your translations into one object with language prefixes as keys and keep rest part of it the same. Then when passing it to view's template use that prefix dynamically.

Comment: But in that case you should re render all your views.